# Where is the hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have hadoop installed (single-node) installed on my machine.  How do I interact with the hdfs?

I thought that creating a directory using hadoop fs mkdir would have everything in that directory be in the hdfs, but I can interact write into that directory using normal linux commands.  Perhaps I am completely misunderstanding how the file system works, but I thought it was append only and can only be accessed using its api.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop has three types of installation:

1. Distributed mode (cluster)
2. Pseudo-distributed mode (single node)
3. Local mode (single node)

In first two modes HDFS is installed. But in third mode HDFS doesn't exists, but emulated. You can call commands like "$hadoop fs -ls", but it will works with your local filesystem, not with hdfs.

Also, HDFS is not full functional file-system. To interact with it you should use commands in view:

- **hadoop fs -ls**
- **hadoop fs -mkdir** your_directory
- **hadoop fs -cat** your_file

etc.

HDFS can't be mounted to your linux filesystem (at least without additional software), and supports limited commands. Also you can't put files to hdfs using "cp" command. You should use

**hadoop fs -put** local_file_or_directory

To copy files from hdfs to your local filesystem you should use:

**hadoop fs -get** *filename*

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is a file system on top of the OS file system, each running in it's own namespace. So, HDFS namespace is not visible in the OS namespace and . Use the hadoop fs [commands](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/file_system_shell.html) to interact with the HDFS namespace.

The metadata (folders, files in each folder, folder to block mapping) is stored in the fsImage in the NameNode. The [offline image viewer](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/hdfs_imageviewer.html) can be used to see the contents of the fsImage file on the NameNode.